# Import several sheets from the same excel into one dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have **one** excel file with several identical structured sheets on it (same headers and number of columns) (sheetsname: 01,02,...,12).

How can I get this into one dataframe?

Right now I would load it all seperate with:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name='01')
df2 = pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name='02')
...
```

and would then concentate it.
What is the most pythonic way to do it and get directly one dataframe with all the sheets? Also assumping I do not know every sheetname in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the file as:

```
collection =  pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name=None)

combined = pd.concat([value.assign(sheet_source=key)
                      for key,value in collection.items()],
                     ignore_index=True)
```

sheet_name = None ensures all the sheets are read in.
 
collection is a dictionary, with the sheet_name as key, and the actual data as the values.
 combined uses the pandas concat method to get you one dataframe.
 I added the extra column sheet_source, in case you need to track where the data for each row comes from.

You can read more about it on the pandas [doco](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
df_final = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('path.xls', sheet_name="{:02d}".format(sheet)) for sheet in range(12)], axis=0)
```

Comment: that would mean i sitll have to manually write it for every sheet..

Comment: this I  don't know in advance